# Paypal express checkout not working on sandbox

Tags: paypal

We have integrated paypal express checkout in our application 1 year back and it was working just fine till last week. It still works fine on Live environment, the issue is with sandbox.

We get below error

> The Request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

On doing some search I found that there are some changes on Pyapal API. I did changes in endpoint as mentioned in API document but still it doesn't work. Anybody is facing the same and it would be great if you can give some working sample with new API changes.

Comment: Your server supports ssl, right?  Can you link the changelog? The changelogs between your last version and your recent version.

Comment: Yes, server supports SSL. But same application used to be working on local machine as well and I don't think I need to install some certificate on local machine.

Comment: It's safer to have one, anyway. Regardless, version info--better, changelogs--would really help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your return url is SSL (https) and your certificate has expired?